# java.lang.NullPointerException when setting text to Label

Tags: java, javafx

Every time I try to set the text to the label 'lblTaskName' I get 'java.lang.NullPointerException'. After trying to debug, I found that the label itself was somehow null.
Here is the code below:
My TaskObject controller class

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TaskObjectController

{
    @FXML
    BorderPane taskpane;

    @FXML
    Label lblTaskName;

    @FXML
    Button taskindicator;

    @FXML
    Label lblduedate;


    BorderPane view;



    public void setTask(TaskStructure obj, boolean today) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(obj.getName()+"--"+obj.getSubject());
        lblTaskName.setText("test");

        if (today)
        {
            lblduedate.setText("Today");
        }
        else
        {
            lblduedate.setText(obj.getDatedue().toString());
        }
    }
```

Snippet of my controller class for the screen where all tasks will be listed.

```
public void initialize() throws IOException {
        String line = "";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Users/aliabdullah/Desktop/FXML-Example/src/sample/UpcomingTasks");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            LocalDate datedue = LocalDate.parse(values[0]);
            String task = values[1];
            String subject = values[2];
            LocalDate dateset = LocalDate.parse(values[3]);
            LocalDate datecompleted = LocalDate.parse(values[4]);
            Boolean completed = Boolean.parseBoolean(values[5]);


            tasklist.add(new TaskStructure(datedue, task, subject, dateset, datecompleted, completed)); //tasklist is an arraylist of type task structure  (a class i made so that its objects would have specific attributes like name, subject, datedue e.t.c.


        }

        int size = tasklist.size();

        try { //load task items to vbox
            Node[] nodes = new Node[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length ; i++) {
                //load specific item
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TaskObject.fxml"));
                TaskObjectController controller = new TaskObjectController();
                loader.setController(controller);
                Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
                nodes[i] = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TaskObject.fxml"));
                System.out.println(nodes[i]);
                completedbox.getChildren().add(nodes[i]);

                if (!tasklist.get(i).completed && (tasklist.get(i).getDatedue().equals(LocalDate.now()))) {
                 
                 controller.setTask(tasklist.get(i), true);
                }
                if (!tasklist.get(i).completed && (!tasklist.get(i).getDatedue().equals(LocalDate.now()))) {
                   
                    controller.setTask(tasklist.get(i), false,i);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong");
            e.printStackTrace();


        }


    }
```

Here is the FXML of my Tasks Screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="rootLayout" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1440.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.SampleController">
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="175.0" layoutY="-14.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="555.0" spacing="100.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="45.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="TASKS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Gill Sans" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="timerbutton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changescreenTimer" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="TIMER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Gill Sans" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="DATA">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Gill Sans" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="555.0" rotate="90.0" spacing="100.0" translateX="935.0" translateY="400.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="681.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="SCHOOL">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Gill Sans" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="OTHER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Gill Sans" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="805.0" prefWidth="1385.0">
         <children>
            <BorderPane prefHeight="856.0" prefWidth="1391.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="-51.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-7.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <center>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="409.0" prefWidth="1384.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <center>
                        <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollpanetop" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" prefHeight="339.0" prefWidth="1384.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                           <content>
                              <VBox fx:id="completedbox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="1382.0" />
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
               </center>
               <bottom>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="1384.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <center>
                        <ScrollPane prefHeight="442.0" prefWidth="1384.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                           <content>
                              <VBox fx:id="incompletebox" prefHeight="372.0" prefWidth="1380.0" />
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
               </bottom>
               <top>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="66.0" prefWidth="1384.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <center>
                        <BorderPane prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="1384.0" style="-fx-border-color: #adadad#adadad;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                           <center>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="342.0" text="TASKS" translateX="30.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="Gill Sans" size="50.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </center>
                           <right>
                              <Button fx:id="newtaskbutton" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changescreennewTask" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="60.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 50;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                 <graphic>
                                    <ImageView fitHeight="52.0" fitWidth="43.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                       <image>
                                          <Image url="@add.png" />
                                       </image>
                                    </ImageView>
                                 </graphic>
                              </Button>
                           </right>
                        </BorderPane>
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
               </top>
            </BorderPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and here is the FXML of my TaskObject

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1382.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FBFCFC; -fx-background-radius: 50; -fx-border-radius: 50;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.TaskObjectController">
   <center>
      <Label fx:id="lblTaskName" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="1000.0" textAlignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
         <padding>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </padding>
         <font>
            <Font name="Gill Sans" size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </center>
   <padding>
      <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
   </padding>
   <left>
      <Button fx:id="taskindicator" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 100; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-background-color: #FBFCFC #FBFCFC; -fx-border-color: grey; -fx-border-radius: 100;" textFill="#dcf6ff" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Gill Sans" size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </left>
   <right>
      <Label fx:id="lblduedate" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="300.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="300.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-border-color: grey; -fx-background-radius: 200; -fx-border-radius: 200;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Gill Sans" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

How do i make it so that every time I want to add a new task, it adds a new TaskObject to the vbox and I can have each TaskObject have a different label.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Post the complete stack trace (format it as code), and indicate which lines in the code. are throwing the exception. And as suggested, create a [mre]: you should only need to load one copy of `TaskObject.fxml` and you should be able to significantly reduce the complexity of the example to reproduce this.